# problems displaying my array via JSON object

Tags: json, jquery

Hi I am having a problems displaying my array via JSON object. I passed two variables to PHP which returns an array. I then wish to loop through the array and append the result to a div

The PHP works fine as I have tested this before adding the JQuery. When I use google chrome to inspect the console, I dump out data which displays as [] not an object, is this correct?

the contents of the array do not have a key, only a collection of list items with an image path for example

```
<li><img src="'.$image_path.'"</li>
```

I encode the array back to the listener,

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

code for JQuery

```
$.post('Look_Controller.php', {look: look, account: account}, function(data) {                              
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('#carousel-ul').empty();
        content = item;
       $(content).appendTo('#carousel-ul');
});
    }, "json");
```

How do I append each individual result to the div (#carousel-ul)?,

I have also tried

```
content = item.this;
content = (this).item;
content = $(this).item;
```

I am not sure if it because the console.log(data) displays [] instead of object?

Hope someone can advise!

Thanks

Comment: It is better to move the `append/empty` outside `.each` function.

Comment: I have moved this outside the .each loop as suggested, thanks SKS but still nothing just [] console output!

Comment: `$('#carousel-ul')` exists? What happens if you console.log($('#carousel-ul')); ?

Comment: ...And what if you `console.log(item)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` is an empty array.  If that's what's being shown you have no data.

So it's probably not coming back from the server.  Check the Network tab in the Chrome debugger and see what your response looks like.

Comment: yes I had a variable in the wrong place when I copied the code across from testing, Thanks for your advice,

Answer (score 1):

What happen when you try this ?

```
$.post('Look_Controller.php', {look: look, account: account}, function(data) {                              
$('#carousel-ul').empty();
console.log(data);
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item);
    content = item;
    // If "carousel-ul" is a <ul> tag uncomment the next line
    // content = $('<li/>').html(content);
   $(content).appendTo('#carousel-ul');
});
}, "json");
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice marmadrood I will have a look at this